# Exception thrown: read access violation. **this** was nullptr. occurred

Tags: c++

I am a novice at C++. I have started writing a rather large code on a project and I want to make a good base for that. I get the following error when running in Visual Studio:

Exception thrown: read access violation. **this** was nullptr. occurred

After searching similar questions, I could not find the solution for my code. The error is occurring in Driver.cpp at:
m_setup->SetEquation(...)

Any help is really appreciated. I also appreciate if you have suggestion to improve my code structure.

Main.h:

```
#ifndef FEM_AD1D_MAIN_H
#define FEM_AD1D_MAIN_H

namespace FEM_AD1D
{
    class Driver;
    Driver* m_driver;
}
#endif
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Main.h"
#include "Driver.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace FEM_AD1D;


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    m_driver->Run();
}
```

Driver.h:

```
#ifndef FEM_AD1D_DRIVER_H
#define FEM_AD1D_DRIVER_H

namespace FEM_AD1D
{
    class Setup;

    class Driver
    {
    public:

        Driver(Setup* setup);

        void Run();
        void PreProc();

    private:

        Setup* m_setup;

        const int m_nDim = 1;
        const double m_aCoef = 1.0;
        const double m_bCoef = 3.0;
        const double m_cCoef = 0.0;
        const double m_fCoef = 1.0;

        const double m_xMin = 0.0;
        const double m_xMax = 1.0;

        const int m_nElem = 5;
        const int m_elemType = 2;
        const double m_meshStretch = 0.0;

        const int m_nGaussPoint = 3;
    };
}
#endif
```

Driver.cpp:

```
#include "Driver.h"
#include "Setup.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace FEM_AD1D;


Driver::Driver(Setup* setup)
{
    m_setup = setup;
    //m_setup = new Setup();
}


void Driver::Run()
{
    PreProc();
}

void Driver::PreProc()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World 2!\n";
    m_setup->SetEquation(m_nDim, m_aCoef, m_bCoef, m_cCoef, m_fCoef);
}
```

Setup.h:

```
#ifndef FEM_AD1D_SETUP_H
#define FEM_AD1D_SETUP_H

#include <vector>

namespace FEM_AD1D

{
    class Setup
    {
    public:

        Setup();

        void SetEquation(int nDim, double aCoef, double bCoef, double cCoef, double fCoef);

    private:

        int m_nDim;
        double m_aCoef;
        double m_bCoef;
        double m_cCoef;
        double m_fCoef;
    };
}
#endif
```

Setup.cpp:

```
#include "Setup.h"
#include "Driver.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace FEM_AD1D;

Setup::Setup() :
    m_nDim(0),
    m_aCoef(0.0),
    m_bCoef(0.0),
    m_cCoef(0.0),
    m_fCoef(0.0)
{
}

void Setup::SetEquation(int nDim, double aCoef, double bCoef, double cCoef, double fCoef)
{
    // Set the coefficients of the equation 
    std::cout << "Hello World 3!\n";
    m_nDim = nDim;
    m_aCoef = aCoef;
    m_bCoef = bCoef;
    m_cCoef = cCoef;
    m_fCoef = fCoef;
}
```

Comment: Presumably, `m_setup` is `nullptr` at that point. But that's just a guess, without an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. Probably you pass `nullptr` to the constructor of `Driver` somewhere. A debugger will surely help you here.

Comment: Thank you, @ChrisMM. How can I make m_setup so that it is not nullptr?

Comment: Where is `Driver` being created?

Comment: Thank you, @churill. How can I make m_setup so that it is not nullptr?

Comment: I just added Main.h and Main.cpp where the driver is called.

Comment: You never initialize `m_driver` anywhere. At least not in the code you show. Make sure to have `m_driver = new Dirver( ... )` somewhere and provide meaningful parameters.